# Making a map for iPhone based on pre-prepared google map

Tags: iphone, ipad, google-maps, mapkit

my client prepared google map with points on. Now he wants that points on map in iPhone app. Is there way to export points from map prepared by him ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your client prepared the map in Google Maps, then he can use the "KML" link in his Google Map to download a file with all his data points in it, in KML format.

Answer (score 0):

Did he use javascript to prepare the points and can you get that? If so, use the source.

Did he use maps.google.com to prepare it by dropping points on that? If so, click the URL button and you'll should see the points embedded in the URL, at least that is true for driving directions.

Comment: I don't know yet his method. But is there possibility to get points from his map without coding every single point into map on iPhone. I mean is there possibility to export his map.

Comment: You need to find out how he made the map first.

Comment: He did that manually. But one thing interested me. What if he would use JavaScript ?

Comment: So you have the URL then? Just have an iPhone app go to that hardcoded URL. That should be just some sample code that's already out there. If you are even a newbie iPhone coder you should have that done pretty quick. If not, you'll want to hire someone.